# Openstack IP address Filter

Tags: python, django, ip-address, openstack, keystone

The command : `neutron.list_ports()["ports"]` (Python) gives me all the IP addresses that I have on my machine.

For example:

```
[{u'status': u'ACTIVE',
 u'name': u'',
 u'allowed_address_pairs': [],
 u'admin_state_up': True,
 u'network_id': u'7da####81c2##79e2',
 u'dns_name': u'',
 u'extra_dhcp_opts': [],
 u'dns_assignment': [{u'hostname': u'host-193-164-#5-##',
 u'ip_address': u'193.164.#5.##',
 u'fqdn': u'host-193-164-#5-##.openstacklocal.'}],
 u'binding:vnic_type': u'normal',
 u'device_owner': u'compute:None',
 u'tenant_id': u'155##748a###3895###8b890',
 u'mac_address': u'fa:##:3e:##:##:cr',
 u'port_security_enabled': True,
 u'fixed_ips': [{u'subnet_id': u'66####e6-###-####-a7#f-4017###6d762',
 u'ip_address': u'193.164.#5.##'}],
 u'id': u'170##4c7d-571f-###-a089-5c4###97d29',
 u'security_groups': [u'ba6d##2-bd#58-40#c2-a5c#2-9###92a4##e'],
 u'device_id': u'da##5d-###-4d6f-b##b-c3###8435'},

 {u'status': u'DOWN',
 u'name': u'',
 u'allowed_address_pairs': [],
 u'admin_state_up': True,
 u'network_id': u'##',
 u'dns_name': u'',
 u'extra_dhcp_opts': [],
 u'dns_assignment': [{u'hostname': u'host-##',
 u'ip_address': u'##',
 u'fqdn': u'host-##.openstacklocal.'}],
 u'binding:vnic_type': u'normal',
 u'device_owner': u'',
 u'tenant_id': u'##',
 u'mac_address': u'f##9:f7',
 u'port_security_enabled': True,
 u'fixed_ips': [{u'subnet_id': u'##62',
 u'ip_address': u'####'}],
 u'id': u'34f##b7c-######9138-##39##30e9',
 u'security_groups': [u'ba##-bd58-40##5c2-9##92a4##'],
 u'device_id': u''}]
```

I put the "#" to hide the IPs...

I want to be able to distinguish between three type of IPs :

1. A resevered and allocated IP
2. A reservered and NonAllocated IP
3. A NonReserved but Allocated IP

Comment: how to find out what applies IP? Allocated or none, what the line answers.

Answer (score 0):

list -> num -> dict

```
a = [{'name': 'one'}, {'name': 'two'}]
a[0]['name']
```

access to elements

```
network = neutron.list_ports()["ports"]
for elem in network:
    print a['status']
    print a['network_id']
    print a['ip_address']
    print a['dns_assignment'][0]['ip_address']
```